# Get the browser url inside my Canvas app

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, powerapp, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

I need to get the browser URL inside Power App canvas standalone app, is this possible?

I do not want to get parameters, I want the whole URL.

Comment: Are you embedding canvas app in SharePoint page and wants to get the page URL in app?

Comment: @GaneshSanap no i want to get the power app url as a standalone app

Comment: You can get the GUID of app & then construct URL in required format. Let me know if this helps: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Getting-current-apps-GUID-ID-within-the-app/td-p/259694

Comment: Hi @johnGu, did you try suggestions given in my below answer? Is it working for you?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read the complete browser URL using the default functions available in Power Apps.

However, you can get the app details like GUID, app name, description, etc. using Power Apps for Makers connector.

Example: Below gives you GUID of the application:

```
LookUp(
    PowerAppsforAdmins.GetAdminApps(
        LookUp(
            PowerPlatformforAdmins.GetAdminEnvironment().value,
            properties.creationType = "DefaultTenant"
        ).name
    ).value,
    properties.displayName="yourAppName"
).name
```

Once you get the GUID of application, you can construct the URL in specific format like:

```
https://apps.powerapps.com/play/{App ID}?{Query}
```

OR:

```
https://apps.powerapps.com/play/e/{Environment ID}/a/{App ID}?{Query}
```

**References**:

1. [Getting current apps GUID ID within the app](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Getting-current-apps-GUID-ID-within-the-app/td-p/259694)
2. [How do I get the App name inside my canvas app?](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-do-I-get-the-App-name-inside-my-canvas-app/td-p/699906)

---

Not sure if this works for end users without  Environment Maker security role. But, if you are using default environment, it should work.

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.  It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.