# In Power Apps, how do I refer to the application in code?

Tags: office-365, administration, powerapp, powerapps-canvas, formula

Let's say I have an application, "My Power App", in Power Apps.

How, in code, do I get the property "My Power App" to put it in a log, for example?

Power Automate has the `workflow()` property. What's the equivalent in Power Apps, to refer to "This application I am currently in"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Power Apps for Makers** connector to get the information related to your Power Apps application.

You can use formula like below to get the display name of your application:

```
PowerAppsforMakers.GetApp("674e1e0-3r23-....").properties.displayName​
```

**OR**

```
LookUp(
    PowerAppsforMakers.GetApps().value,
    name = "674e1e0-3r23-...." // app ID
).properties.displayName
```

Where `674e1e0-3r23-....` is the **App ID** of your Power Apps application. You can get it from **Details** page of your canvas application.

---

**Documentation**: [Power Apps for Makers connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/powerappsforappmakers/)

**Additional Reference**: [Get the browser url inside my Canvas app](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304195/get-the-browser-url-inside-my-canvas-app/304198#304198)